# RestAssured content-type application/json not being recognised by service

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, rest-assured

I have a service, which I can access with the following jQuery code (from google chrome with --disable-web-security)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://10.30.1.2:9234/myapp/v6/token/generate",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Accept":"application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
      "staffId" : "13254",
      "password" : "JustADummyPassword"
    })
}).done(function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://10.30.1.2:9234/myapp/v6/user/appl/Firstname/Lastname/email@address.com/1998-01-01",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Accept":"application/json"
    }
}).done(function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

The first call sets a cookie, which is required for the second call to authenticate. This works fine, and both requests return expected results.

I am trying to set up automated testing for the service, and have this written in JAVA, using RestAssured.

```
public class UserApplication {
    public static Map<String, String> authCookies = null;
    public static String JSESSIONID = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response resp = hello();
        resp = apiUserApplication();
    }

    public static Response apiUserApplication() {
        String userAppl = "http://10.30.1.2:9234/myapp/v6/user/appl/Firstname/Lastname/email@address.com/1998-01-01";

        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .cookie("JSESSIONID", JSESSIONID).and()
                .header("Accept", "application/json").and()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json").and()
                .when().get(userAppl);

        return response;
    }

    public static Response hello() {
        String helloUrl = "http://10.30.1.2:9234/myapp/v6/hello";

        Response response = RestAssured.given().cookies(authCookies)
                .contentType("application/json").when().get(helloUrl);

        return response;
    }
}
```

The first call (hello) works fine, and returns 200 code, and gets a valid token for use in the second call. The error I am getting from the second call with a 400 status code is...

```
{"errors":["Content type 'null' not supported"]}
```

Comment: Did you try to specify content type with `.contentType` method?

Comment: @ilya yes I did, and it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Can you check to see if any of the other apiUserApplication attributes get transferred over? Is there an error log?

Comment: It looks like JSESSIONID and authCookies are initialized as null and not changing in this code. Can it be a reason?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with `RestAssured`, but your code is set up to first call, `hello`, then `apiUserApplication`. You have some class level variables that you default to `null`, but you never explicitly give them a value. In particular, it looks in the second call, `apiUserApplication`, you are setting the value of the cookie to a null value.

I also do not see why you are returning this response object? It would make sense if you were to examine it, ensure that the response has data as you expected and that you then set this session ID for the second request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `JSESSIONID` and `authCookies` are initialized as `null` and not changing in this code.